# How to add controls into a new tab page which is dynamically created?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview, tabcontrol

I am developing a windows form application in C# which has a tab control with dynamically created tab pages. I want to add same layout and controls (ComboBoxes, TextBoxes, Buttons & DataGridView) from `ComboSet Item 1` to a newly created tab page (`ComboSet Item 2` in this case). How can I do that and how to name the controls?

[image]

New tabs will be generated from `1,2,3... n`. So 'n' number of DataGridViews will be also added under the new tabs. Is there a way to bind these DataGridViews and is it possible to do so?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new user control->Place all controls into user control->create the properties for all controls. then you just have to manage only your user control.

```
void AddTab()
{
    TabPage tbp = new TabPage();
    tbp.Name=TabControl1.TabPages.Count.ToString();
    MyUserControl cnt = new MyUserControl();
    cnt.Name="Cnt" + tbp.Name;
    cnt.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;
    tbp.Controls.Add(cnt);
}
```

If you cannot place your code into the user control then you can  create events for each control. for example ProductName_SelectedValueChange for ProductName combobox, Validating for Discount value and handle it into AddTab() method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solves my first question. But I still have a problem with binding DataGridView. The only thing I don't understand is when I create my own `UserControl`, I have to use the same control name for all ComboSet Items right? E.g. If I use a DataGridView named `dgrdCS` under new tabs for different data, how can I manage to bind them? Replaced the old data and bind with new data?

Comment: you can find your DataGridView Control as

MyUserControl cnt = (MyUserControl)TabControl.TabPages[Index].Controls[0];
cnt.grid.DataSouce = dtTable; grid will perform just like a property so you don't need to specify name for each grid control. and you can manage your tab by either name or index.

Comment: I write the code for DataGridView in User Control form to bind the data source. I marked your answer as my final solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

TabPages are normal container like Panel. 
You can use the `tabpage.controls.add()` method to add some new items. If you want to name a item use the `myitem.Name = "Test"` Property. 
If you want a fix set of items on more pages you should create a Usercontrol for it.

Comment: I can add new tab pages using `tabpage.Controls.Add()` method. But I am having the problem with placing the controls fit into a tab page and naming them.

Comment: I tried this tabPage1.Controls.Add(new TextBox()); and it works. Make sure that you dont add controls on tabcontrol! You need to choose the tabpage! In TabControl you just add new Tabpages! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to add more controls to the tab page, I suggest to create an own UserControl for the content in the tabe page.

Arrange the controls in the UserControl as you need it (DockStyle, Anchor...).

When you create a new tab just create a new UserControl and add it to the tab page as mentioned by Sebi. Additionally you should set the DockStyle to Fill. That should so the trick.